# Dplyr count not working inside of mutate when counting factors

Tags: dplyr, count, mutate

I'm processing some eye-tracking data and trying to calculate the number of fixations within an area of interest grouped by participant, WHR, BMI and AOI_new. However, I get an error when I attempt to use count within a mutate function.

When I try and use dplyr::count() inside of either a mutuate (or summarise) function:

```
fix_df_summed <- fix_df_final %>% group_by(participant, AOI_new, WHR, BMI) %>% 
                                  summarise(total_dwell_time = sum(dur)) %>% 
                                  mutate(number_of_fixations = count(AOI_new))
```

I get the error:

```
ℹ In argument: `number_of_fixations = dplyr::count(AOI_new)`.
ℹ In group 1: `participant = 1`, `AOI_new = Head`, `WHR = "0.6"`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "factor"
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% mutate(number_of_fixations = dplyr::count(AOI_new))
 9. dplyr::count(AOI_new)
```

However, when I use the following code it works perfectly fine:

```
fix_df_final %>% group_by(participant, AOI_new, WHR, BMI) %>% dplyr::count(AOI_new)
```

However, the moment I add mutate it produces the same error as above. I'm unsure what the difference is between these bits of code. Can anyone offer any solutions?

Comment: I think the issue is not mutate, it is the summarize. You are using AOI_new as a grouping variable, so in the resulting data set  i'm not sure what you are counting.  Can you please add what you want your final data to look like?

Comment: `fix_df_summed <- fix_df_final %>% group_by(participant, AOI_new, WHR, BMI) %>% 
                                  summarise(total_dwell_time = sum(dur),
                                            number_of_fixations = n())`

Comment: I think you are looking for `n()` instead of `count()`. Or if you only want to count unique fixations, try `length(unique(AOI_new))`

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! @PaulMaxwell, your solution worked perfectly. I had tried using n(), but not inside of the summarise function.